How to add escape character with bash?
I want this
{@codeBlock: TEstBigquerry.buildPicks}

to become
\{@codeBlock: TEstBigquerry.buildPicks/}

I tried
sed -i '/{@/\{@' joana.txt

got
sed: -e expression #1, char 5: unknown command: `'
how to add an escape string two times?

To escape properly, assuming your input is a typo ¹ :
$ printf '%q\n' '{@codeBlock: TEstBigquerry.buildPicks}'
\{@codeBlock:\ TEstBigquerry.buildPicks\}

¹: to escape, you need backslash: \ not slash: /

yes,that works fine.

You doubted? :D

No,not at all,thanks.

Please, fix your typos in your post

Can I used this with loop? check condition if line contains  @codeBlock?

printf %q does shell-like quoting. The OP's input doesn't look shell related. If it was to be quoted so as to be used in shell syntax, that { wouldn't need to be escaped, but spaces would.

ok,I will post new question.
